# How to add data from one data frame to another based on time using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following 2 data frames;

```
df2 = 
   Date Time                Fuel Type
1  25/10/2023  09:00:00     D1
2  25/10/2023  16:35:00
3  26/10/2023  09:00:00     D2

df1 =
   Date Time                Test Fuel
1  25/10/2023 09:24         4196
2  25/10/2023 13:24         3465
3  26/10/2023 09:55         4566
```

I want to look up data from df2 to create the following (I want to assume the fuel type is still D1 as it hasn't been updated);

```
df1 =
   Date Time                Test Fuel   Fuel Type
1  25/10/2023 09:24         4196        D1
2  25/10/2023 13:24         3465        D1
3  26/10/2023 09:55         4566        D2
```

I'm not sure if this is possible as the dates don't match

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an outer merge for these two dataframes, filter so that only row where test fuel time is greater or equal than fuel type time, then get only last row for each test fuel:

```
df1["key"] = 1
df2["key"] = 1

df = df1 \
    .merge(df2, on="key", suffixes=[None, " type"])

df[df["Date Time"] >= df["Date Time type"]] \
    .sort_values(["Date Time", "Test Fuel", "Date Time type"]) \
    .groupby(["Date Time", "Test Fuel"], as_index=False) \
    [["Fuel Type"]] \
    .last()
```

Output:

```
            Date Time  Test Fuel Fuel Type
0 2023-10-25 09:24:00       4196        D1
1 2023-10-25 13:24:00       3465        D1
2 2023-10-26 09:55:00       4566        D2
```

Just in case - this is how I created dataframes from your input examples:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date Time": ["25/10/2023  09:00:00", "25/10/2023  16:35:00", "26/10/2023  09:00:00"],
    "Fuel Type": ["D1", None, "D2"]
})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date Time": ["25/10/2023 09:24", "25/10/2023 13:24", "26/10/2023 09:55"],
    "Test Fuel": [4196, 3465, 4566]
})

df2["Date Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Date Time"])
df1["Date Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date Time"])
```

Answer (score 0):

`pd.merge_asof` seems to be sufficient for the example you shared:

```py
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='Date Time')
Out[218]: 
            Date Time  Test Fuel Fuel Type
0 2023-10-25 09:24:00       4196        D1
1 2023-10-25 13:24:00       3465        D1
2 2023-10-26 09:55:00       4566        D2
```